# nth-child() not displaying in print media

Tags: css, printing, media, css-selectors

Ignoring the table made of divs (believe me, I've had that discussion with the powers that be), I am having trouble getting my alternating row background colors to view for my print media.  Here is what I've got:

```
<div class="table">
   <div class="head">
     <div class="headcell">Column 1 is this long</div>
     <div class="headcell">Column 2 but this neeeds to be this long</div>
     <div class="headcell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="cell">Column 1 is this long</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 2 but this neeeds to be this lonn</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="cell">Column 1</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 2</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="cell">Column 1</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 2</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="cell">Column 1</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 2</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="cell">Column 1</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 2</div>
     <div class="cell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
@media print
{
h1  {
  margin-top: 17.67pt;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16pt;
  margin-bottom: 1.67pt;
  padding-left: none;
  background-image: none;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

/*Table made of Divs PDF Styles*/
.table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: table;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px; 
}

.head {
  display: table-row;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  padding:4px 10px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
}

.headcell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  font-align: center;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
}

div.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

div.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
}
```

I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot force to print the end-user to print background colors. This is a printer setting in the browser which can be turned off. That is why it does not work.
Your nth-child selectors work just fine. See screen shot below of the print preview.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gjf8K/3/

```
 @media print {
  div.row:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc;
   color: red;
  }
  div.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: green;
  }
 }
```

[image: print preview]

Comment: Ahhh, I was hoping it wasn't related to the print functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @JohanVdR good answer with the perfect example demonstrating the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can force the print view to use exact colors by adding this code to your style:

```
 body{ 
    print-color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can have this css code to customize the background of rows one in one way and the one before in another way (even and odd rows)

```
    //*Odd cells
    div.row:nth-child(even) div.cell {
       background-color: #000000;
       color: white;
      }

    //* Even cells
div.row:nth-child(odd) div.cell {
       background-color: #000000;
       color: white;
      }
```

Comment: Whaa? o_O I don't even... (and what is `rwhite`?)

Comment: what is retaliative downvoting to my comment?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake with typing. rwhite = white (the color); i didn't vote, actually I don't have the power of voting :/

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't think about that. I still don't understand what you were trying to code though... both selectors are the same. Did you mean `div.row:nth-child(odd)` and `div.row:nth-child(even)`?

Comment: yes sorry again. i was really sleeping yesterday sorry mate